# Why isn't the function is_null accurate with $_FILES?

Tags: php

I want to test if the user selected a file or not , so I tested if `$_FILES['input_name']['name']` is not null.

I used the PHP function `is_null($_FILES['input_name']['name'])` but the code goes to the statements where it's supposed a file was selected !

So I replaced my test with `$_FILES['input_name']['name'] != ""` .

So why isn't `is_null` accurate with $_FILES['name'] ?

Comment: Because the value is not `null`. `var_dump($_FILES)` to see what it actually is.

Comment: @pheromix did you saw my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `empty()` function instead of `== ""`

Comment: Not necessarily. Use `empty` if you do not know whether the variable exists or not and you want to compare it to `false`. The *do not know whether it exists* part is important; if the variable *should* exist then don't use `empty`. Also, `"0"` is also `empty`!

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget, null is not the same as "".

"" represents an empty string whereas null could represent an uninitialized string.

Comment: No, `null` represents `null`, that is an own data type, where `null` is the only possible value

Comment: @KingCrunch I know but I was trying to find another way of saying it :P

Answer (score 3):

Is_null is not the same as '' (empty string).

This easy been seen when var_dumping the value!

Comment: just use "empty()" to check for null and emptyness.

Comment: After var_dumping $_FILES I got this : `array(1) { ["post_photo"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(4) ["size"]=> int(0) } }` . So what does it mean ?

Comment: It says: ["name"]=> string(0) "" meaning it is a empty string, has a value of ''. It has certainly not the NULL value. Use Empty() to check!

Answer (score 2):

well it means $_FILES array is not initialized as NULL valued array. I think you must use `empty()` instead

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 1):

The is_null(var) returns TRUE if var is null, FALSE otherwise.

```
if(is_null($_FILES['input_name']['name'])){
 block of code;//file name is null
}
```